# C++ ambiguous symbol error

Tags: c++, boost

I'm building Quantlib using Boost libraries in VS2013. I built Boost using NuGet package manager in VS2013.

I am getting 50 instances of ambiguous symbol error in my build. All the errors are related to the same variable: ***tolerance*** . Below is a sample cpp file where the variable is declared and then accessed. I get errors in lines 51,77, and 98, the three instance where the variable ***tolerance*** is used.

The namespace is defined without any ***namespace_name*** and there is no ***using  namespace namespace_name;*** line. I don't know if this is an issue or if the issue is something else. I am a total newb with C++ so I will appreciate any help to fix this.

```
#include "tqreigendecomposition.hpp"
#include "utilities.hpp"
#include <ql/math/matrixutilities/tqreigendecomposition.hpp>

using namespace QuantLib;
using namespace boost::unit_test_framework;

namespace {

    Real tolerance = 1.0e-10;

}


void TqrEigenDecompositionTest::testEigenValueDecomposition() {
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Testing TQR eigenvalue decomposition...");

    Array diag(5);
    Array sub(4,1);
    diag[0]=11; diag[1]=7; diag[2]=6; diag[3]=2; diag[4]=0;
    Real ev[5] = {11.2467832217139119,
                  7.4854967362908535,
                  5.5251516080277518,
                  2.1811760273123308,
                  -0.4386075933448487};

    TqrEigenDecomposition tqre(diag, sub,
                               TqrEigenDecomposition::WithoutEigenVector);
    for (Size i=0; i < diag.size(); ++i) {
        const Real expected(ev[i]);
        const Real calculated(tqre.eigenvalues()[i]);
        if (std::fabs(expected-calculated) > tolerance) {
            BOOST_FAIL(std::string("wrong eigenvalue \n")
                       << "calculated: "
                       << calculated
                       <<" expected  : "
                       << expected);
        }
    }
}

void TqrEigenDecompositionTest::testZeroOffDiagEigenValues() {
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Testing TQR zero-off-diagonal eigenvalues...");

    Array diag(5);
    Array sub(4,1);
    sub[0] =sub[2]=0;
    diag[0]=12; diag[1]=9; diag[2]=6; diag[3]=3; diag[4]=0;

    TqrEigenDecomposition tqre1(diag, sub);

    sub[0]=sub[2]=1e-14;
    TqrEigenDecomposition tqre2(diag, sub);

    for (Size i=0; i < diag.size(); ++i) {
        const Real expected(tqre2.eigenvalues()[i]);
        const Real calculated(tqre1.eigenvalues()[i]);
        if (std::fabs(expected-calculated) > tolerance) {
            BOOST_FAIL(std::string("wrong eigenvalue \n")
                       << "calculated: "
                       << calculated
                       << " expected  : "
                       << expected);
        }
    }
}

void TqrEigenDecompositionTest::testEigenVectorDecomposition() {
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Testing TQR eigenvector decomposition...");

    Array diag(2,1);
    Array sub(1,1);

    TqrEigenDecomposition tqre(diag, sub);

    if (std::fabs(0.25 + tqre.eigenvectors()[0][0]
                       * tqre.eigenvectors()[0][1]
                       * tqre.eigenvectors()[1][0]
                       * tqre.eigenvectors()[1][1]) > tolerance) {
        BOOST_FAIL("wrong eigenvector");
    }
}

test_suite* TqrEigenDecompositionTest::suite() {
    test_suite* suite = BOOST_TEST_SUITE("TQR eigendecomposition tests");
    suite->add(QUANTLIB_TEST_CASE(
                   &TqrEigenDecompositionTest::testEigenValueDecomposition));
    suite->add(QUANTLIB_TEST_CASE(
                   &TqrEigenDecompositionTest::testZeroOffDiagEigenValues));
    suite->add(QUANTLIB_TEST_CASE(
                   &TqrEigenDecompositionTest::testEigenVectorDecomposition));
    return suite;
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Full error text (copied from the error list window in VS2013)  I'll look to see if there is a log file somewhere that contains more detail.

```
Error   2   error C2872: 'tolerance' : ambiguous symbol C:\Users\wb459349\QuantLib-1.6\test-suite\tqreigendecomposition.cpp 52  1   testsuite

 tqreigendecomposition.cpp
1>tqreigendecomposition.cpp(52): error C2872: 'tolerance' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'tqreigendecomposition.cpp(30) : QuantLib::Real `anonymous-namespace'::tolerance'
1>          or       'tolerance'
```

Ok so 'tolerance' is defined twice. Once inside the code with the 'anonymous-namespace' and not sure what the second 'tolerance' is, perhaps in one of the two namespaces that whomever built this Quantlib file has invoked when the did the "using namespace ..."

Comment: `using namespace`. You are getting exactly what you have asked for.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for commenting. Unfortunately I don't find your comment actionable.

Comment: You *do* have two `using namespace` lines, and at least one of these namespaces probably contains a `tolerance` symbol which clashes with your `tolerance` from the unnamed namespace. Drop the `using` directives. And, when asking about a compiler error, you should post the full error text - it probably tells you where the other `tolerance` declaration comes from.

Comment: @Angew got it! Thanks! These codes are not written by me. These codes are in the Quantlib libraries that came with Quantlib 1.6 . I'll fix them in the ways that you and ductiletoaster have suggested.

Comment: I would recommend _against_ modifying 3rd party libraries on your system, especially when you're "a total newb with C++". If the library has a bug, [_talk to its author_ instead](http://sourceforge.net/p/quantlib/bugs/). They can tell you what the proper fix is, and apply it via the proper channels. You're just going to break things and ruin version number sanctity.

Comment: `using namespace` is known to cause this kind of errors. You may want to avoid them by only using `using` for namespace members you are actually using. Sorry.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok I'll post this in the Quantlib mailing list.  thank you!

Comment: Excellent! Good luck. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @n.m. said avoid `using namespace` you likely have local/member variables that conflict with those of other libraries.

Example:

```
using namespace std
...
cout << "Foo" << endl;
```

is more ambiguous than

```
...
std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;
```

In summary you have two options.

1. Find all local/member variables that might conflict with those in
   the included libraries and update them.
2. Or two (the preferred method) stop using
       `using namespace` and update all references to use the `::` scope resolution operator.

#### Edit:

I think generally the advice to not use `using` is sound. However, in this particular instance my answer might not be the best advice. As others have mentioned these errors originate within a third-party library and as such it is probably better to point out this incompatibility to the author of this library.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the issue to me. I'll try to implement your suggestions. The codes are all from Quantlib libraries and are not written by me.

Answer (score 0):

### `.vscode/settings.json`

- if there is no error in code

  - according to you and its running fine
- then make sure you check this file ones in root directory
- because of some auto change in settings

  - it was showing error to me in editor